# Updating a mysql database using php via android

Tags: php, android, maps, location

I am trying to update a mysql database using php from an android application.  I have successfully been able to update the database and return data from the database using this tutorial I found here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

I am now trying to update a database using a location provider to obtain the latitude and longitude of a location fix that I am getting via the onLocationChanged callback.  My code looks like this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 


double myLonDouble = location.getLongitude();
String myLon = Double.toString(myLonDouble);
double myLatDouble = location.getLatitude();
String myLat = Double.toString(myLatDouble);

sp = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
id = sp.getInt("id", 0);
String idString = Integer.toString(id);


DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector();

ArrayList<NameValuePair> latLon = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
latLon.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", myLon));
latLon.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", myLat));
latLon.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idString));
tv.setText(idString);
db.dbConnect(latLon, php);
```

}

The method dbConnect, which sends my data to a php file looks like this:

```
public void dbConnect(ArrayList<NameValuePair>  data, String phpFile) {

       InputStream is = null;


        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(phpFile);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();


        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }


     }// end dbConnect
```

The php file that I am using in the httppost object looks like this:

```
>><?php
>>$con = mysql_connect("localhost","********","*********");
>>if (!$con)
>>  {
>>  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
>>  }
>>
>>mysql_select_db("swizzle_practice", $con);
>>
>>$_SQL = 
>>"UPDATE users 
>>SET longitude = '$_REQUEST[longitude]', latitude = '$_REQUEST[latitude]'
>>WHERE id = '$_REQUEST[id]'";    
>>
>>mysql_query($_SQL,$con) or die("error: " . mysql_error());
>>  
>>mysql_close($con)
>>?>
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.first_screen"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".First_screenActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Setup"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Map"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>



</application>
</manifest>
```

I am not getting any errors in the log which leads me to think that it is my code in the 
dbConnect method that is wrong.  I have looked over it and can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.

Louis

Comment: You haven't said what the error is or what's not happening.

Comment: He said that he cannot see if the query affects the db.

Comment: Sorry guys, the db is not being updated with the latitude and longitude that I am getting via the onLocationChanged callback.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'$_REQUEST['longitude']'`, how is now? Log the nameValuePairs to check if the pairs values are correct.

```
$_SQL = 
"UPDATE users 
SET longitude = '$_REQUEST['longitude']', latitude = '$_REQUEST['latitude']'
WHERE id = '$_REQUEST['id']';";
```

P.S: I suggest test your php code and your query with manually inputed values.
And you don't need `response` since you are doing operation which has nothing to do with your application after you send the key-values-pairs, i.e your query does not fetch any data. You can have it and you can use it for outputing if your query did the job or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikola.  When i put the single quote around the value in each of the $_REQUEST brackets (ie 'longitude' instead longitude) is gives me a syntax error on the SET portion of the statement.  It doesn't tell me what the sytax error is but it did not give it to me the way that I had the statement initially formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what data your script received using

```
foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) { 
  echo "$var = $value<br>n"; 
}
```

In your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very good with PHP, but from what I see..you're accessing request variable from `_REQUEST`, but you're setting the request with `HttpPost`.

So to put it straight, you're setting a POST request, but retrieving the variable on the server end as a GET request.  To fix this, either make the client send a GET request or access request variable on the server side from `_POST`